# What is this 3 pin connector?

Tags: identification, dc-motor, connector, servo

I wanted to integrate this piece in one of my projects but I can't find the cable that fits

it's 3 pin and the outside dimensions are:
w : 4.5 mm
h : 2 mm

I tried with a SH1.0 cable but the height is too high

[image][image]

I found it on [aliexpress](https://fr.aliexpress.com/item/1005004461726713.html?spm=a2g0o.detail.1000014.1.4214498ePLUtZ9&gps-id=pcDetailBottomMoreOtherSeller&scm=1007.40050.281175.0&scm_id=1007.40050.281175.0&scm-url=1007.40050.281175.0&pvid=17d3139c-3021-4377-b0fd-9f12f24b9153&_t=gps-id:pcDetailBottomMoreOtherSeller,scm-url:1007.40050.281175.0,pvid:17d3139c-3021-4377-b0fd-9f12f24b9153,tpp_buckets:668%232846%238109%231935&pdp_ext_f=%7B%22sku_id%22%3A%2212000029251839359%22%2C%22sceneId%22%3A%2230050%22%7D&pdp_npi=3%40dis%21CHF%210.98%210.65%21%21%21%21%21%402101c84f16765595101096777ec558%2112000029251839359%21rec%21CH%21)

Comment: Have you tried contacting the seller? Is there a product data sheet for it?

Answer (score 3):

It looks a lot like a JST SUR connector, at 0.8mm pitch.
The height and width are ever-so-slightly off, so you could always remove this connector and replace it with a known plug and socket type.

SUR pre-crimped cables are available, but the IDC tooling is expensive.

https://www.jst.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/eSUR-new.pdf

[image]

Comment: wow thanks for your quick reply i will try it